Image float to next page keeping margin rule in tufte-book
I am using the tufte-book template and I am having a certain issue when images float from a page to another, as I am using the raggedouter option for marginals in the document class.
I already tried to find some help to this matter in the community, but I might be not using quite the most correct terms to look for a hand on this issue and I didn't find anything yet… is there someone who can help me in this?
I'll give you an excerpt of my code where this figure inclusion is being done.
To summarize, in figure~\ref{fig:rank-libraries-full} one can see the current state of the implementation of Rank's libraries of \texttt{rankd-comp} for computing resources, \texttt{rankd-net} for network resources, and \texttt{rankd-time} for timing resources and \acl{tsn} configurations.

\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    %\includegraphics[width=.75\columnwidth]{figs/rank-libraries.pdf}
    \missingfigure[figwidth=\textwidth]{The full integration of components and interactions within the scope of the Rank metrics gatherer libraries}
    \caption{The full integration of components and interactions within the scope of the Rank metrics gatherer libraries}
    \label{fig:rank-libraries-full} 
\end{figure*}

With all the metrics already gathered we can now assess the capabilities of a given machines towards the execution or the schedulability of a given service.

The image placeholder is the outcome of using the \missingfigure command from the todonotes package.
Is there any way to keep the raggedouter option and make this image (and others, since this happens often in the remainder of the document) follow the margins for the next page where the floating image is placed in?
Thank you so much for your help!


Note that if you load the ifoddpage package, tufte-book will use it (\oddpage@label will show up in the aux file).  However, it runs \checkoddpage at the beginning of @tufte@float instead of inside the lrbox where it belongs.  It takes two runs to process changes.
\documentclass[symmetric,marginals=outer]{tufte-book} 
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{@tufte@float}[3][htbp]%
  {% begin @tufte@float
    % Should this float be full-width or just text-width?
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{star}}%
      {\gsetboolean{@tufte@float@star}{true}}%
      {\gsetboolean{@tufte@float@star}{false}}%
    % Check page side (recto/verso) and store detected value -- can be overriden in environment contents
    \stepcounter{checkoddpage}% checkoddpage come later
    \ifoddpage
      \setboolean{@tufte@float@recto}{true}\@tufte@float@debug{Detected page: [recto/odd]}% make changes local
    \else
      \setboolean{@tufte@float@recto}{false}\@tufte@float@debug{Detected page: [verso/even]}%
    \fi
    \addtocounter{checkoddpage}{-1}%
    % If the float placement specifier is 'b' and only 'b', then bottom-align the mini-pages, otherwise top-align them.
    \renewcommand{\@tufte@fps}{#1}%
    \@tufte@float@debug{Allowed positions: [#1]}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{b}\OR\equal{#1}{B}}%
      {\renewcommand{\floatalignment}{b}\@tufte@float@debug{Presumed position: [bottom]}}%
      {\renewcommand{\floatalignment}{t}\@tufte@float@debug{Presumed position: [top]}}%
    % Capture the contents of the \caption and \label commands to use later
    \global\let\@tufte@orig@caption\caption%
    \global\let\@tufte@orig@label\label%
    \renewcommand{\caption}{\optparams{\@tufte@caption}{[][0pt]}}%
    \renewcommand{\label}[1]{\@tufte@label{##1}}%
    % Handle subfigure package compatibility
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@packages@subfigure}}{%
      % don't move the label while inside a \subfigure or \subtable command
      \global\let\label\@tufte@orig@label%
    }{}% subfigure package is not loaded
    \@tufte@orig@float{#2}[#1]%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@float@star}}%
      {\setlength{\@tufte@float@contents@width}{\@tufte@fullwidth}}%
      {\setlength{\@tufte@float@contents@width}{\textwidth}}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@figure@box}%
      \checkoddpage
      \begin{minipage}[\floatalignment]{\@tufte@float@contents@width}\hbox{}%
  }{% end @tufte@float
      \par\hbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\ifthenelse{\prevdepth>0}{\vspace{-\prevdepth}}{}% align baselines of boxes
      \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    % build the caption box
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@caption@box}%
      \begin{minipage}[\floatalignment]{\marginparwidth}\hbox{}%
        \ifthenelse{\NOT\equal{\@tufte@stored@caption}{}}{\@tufte@orig@caption[\@tufte@stored@shortcaption]{\@tufte@stored@caption}}{}%
        \ifthenelse{\NOT\equal{\@tufte@stored@label}{}}{\@tufte@orig@label{\@tufte@stored@label}}{}%
        \par\vspace{-\prevdepth}%% TODO: DOUBLE-CHECK FOR SAFETY
      \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    % now typeset the stored boxes
    \begin{fullwidth}%
      \begin{minipage}[\floatalignment]{\linewidth}%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@float@star}}%
          {\@tufte@float@fullwidth[\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset]{\@tufte@figure@box}{\@tufte@caption@box}}%
          {\@tufte@float@textwidth[\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset]{\@tufte@figure@box}{\@tufte@caption@box}}%
      \end{minipage}%
    \end{fullwidth}%
    \@tufte@orig@endfloat% end original LaTeX float environment
    % output debug info
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@debug}}{%
      \typeout{^^J^^J----------- Tufte-LaTeX float information ----------}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@tufte@stored@label}{}}%
        {\typeout{Warning: Float unlabeled!}}%
        {\typeout{Float label: [\@tufte@stored@label]}}%
      \typeout{Page number: [\thepage]}%
      \def\MessageBreak{^^J}%
      \typeout{\@tufte@float@debug@info}%
      \ifthenelse{\boolean{@tufte@symmetric}}%
        {\typeout{Symmetric: [true]}}%
        {\typeout{Symmetric: [false]}}%
      \typeout{----------------------------------------------------^^J^^J}%
    }{}%
    % reset commands and temp boxes and captions
    \gdef\@tufte@float@debug@info{}%
    \let\caption\@tufte@orig@caption%
    \let\label\@tufte@orig@label%
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@figure@box}\hbox{}\end{lrbox}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@caption@box}\hbox{}\end{lrbox}%
    \gdef\@tufte@stored@shortcaption{}%
    \gdef\@tufte@stored@caption{}%
    \gdef\@tufte@stored@label{}%
    \gsetlength{\@tufte@caption@vertical@offset}{0pt}% reset caption offset
  }
 \makeatother

\begin{document}

\rule{1em}{37\baselineskip}

To summarize, in figure~\ref{fig:rank-libraries-full} one can see the current state of the implementation of Rank's libraries of \texttt{rankd-comp} for computing resources, \texttt{rankd-net} for network resources, and \texttt{rankd-time} for timing resources and \verb|\acl{tsn}| configurations.

\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    %\includegraphics[width=.75\columnwidth]{figs/rank-libraries.pdf}
    \verb|\missingfigure[figwidth=\textwidth]|{The full integration of components and interactions within the scope of the Rank metrics gatherer libraries}
    \caption{The full integration of components and interactions within the scope of the Rank metrics gatherer libraries}
    \label{fig:rank-libraries-full} 
\end{figure*}

With all the metrics already gathered we can now assess the capabilities of a given machines towards the execution or the schedulability of a given service.

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}

